# New git branches not graphically showing as a new branch

Tags: git

I'm not sure what could be possibly wrong in here, but the process is really straight forward, after creating a new repository ( local, not on server and for only one developer, me ), i created a new branch called  **functional_config** from **develop**

As many of you can see, i'm not sure why it didn't created a branch that visually would represent :

```
master-----------------------------------
        \
         develop-------------------------
                      \__functional_config
```

instead of (ignore the version tag please)

[image]

What could i be doing  wrong ? Or i'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the visual representation looks completely legit - you got `master` and `develop` at `Initial Commit`, and the new `functional_config` branch is one commit ahead.

Try to commit something on `master` or `develop`, and you'll see the visual representation "diverge" in a way you are describing...

Comment: this. I believe that i should  delete this question because it was too premature on my behalf to open a question regarding the basic usage of git. Shame on me.

Answer (score 3):

Just because

```
master-----------------------------------
        \
         develop-------------------------
                      \__functional_config
```

is the same to

```
master--
        \
         develop------
                      \__functional_config
```

which is the same to

```
master--develop-------functional_config
```

The last one is what you get.

If you commit smth to your other branches you'll see the exact picture you expect.

Notice additionally that if some branches point to the same commit they are represented by the same row. That is why you have `HEAD`,  `master`, `develop` and `1.35.0` combined. As `functional_config` is one commit ahead, it is separated from them.

Answer (score 0):

A branch is just a dynamic reference to a commit id (the last commit of that branch).

Since you didn't perform any commits after creating (forking) `develop` branch, both `master` and `develop` branches refer to the same (last) commit. That's why they are at the same node (commit id) in the tree.

About branch `functional_config` you have performed a new commit, which makes it to be a child node in the tree. But you don't see the whole commit tree, you only see the nodes that are directly or indirectly parent of the latest commit of current branch. Not other (unrelated) commits from other branches.